# Deriving the formula for velocities of gravitational slingshots using trigonometry

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity

I am working on this article on *'The Slingshot Effect' by R. C. Johnson* (http://maths.dur.ac.uk/~dma0rcj/Psling/sling.pdf) and have become stumped on the derivation of the following equation: 
$$v_{f}^2 = v_{i}^2 + 2 V \{V (1 - \cos\beta) + v_{i}[\cos(\alpha - \beta) - \cos \alpha]\}$$

The question takes two scalene vector triangles as shown below:
[image]

where, angle positions for vector triangles:
[image]

Using this information, one should end up with the equation given above.

It appears that the law of cosines has been used, however I cannot find the final equation as required.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thank you.